# Django random object and use in template

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

First, I'm newbie in Django. My first project is a movie web app, with model as below:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
### movie database ###

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_random(self):
    max_id = Movie.objects.all().aggregate(max_id=Max('id'))['max_id']

    while True:
        pk = random.randint(1, max_id)
        movie = Movie.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
        if movie:
            return movie
```

This "get_random" func only give me 1 return. May I get more than that, let say 10?

I used this model in my "movies_index" template. :

```
{% for movie in movies %}
<a href="{% url 'movies_detail' movie.get_random.pk %}">
<img src="{{ movie.get_random.poster }}" class="img-fluid">
{% endfor %}
```

Webpage can show a movie poster with hyperlink. But when I click to, it go to another movie. Yes, because of I did "random" two time, and get 2 different results.

My question is: how can I choose a set of random and use it consistency in my scenario?

BTW, I'm using CBV as below:

```
class MoviesIndex(ListView):
    model = Movie
    context_object_name = 'movies'
    template_name = 'movies/movies_index.html'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to list your movies object in random order always, you can simply use [**`.order_by('?')`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) while retrieving query set.

Override `get_queryset` method of ListView

```
class MoviesIndex(ListView):
    model = Movie
    context_object_name = 'movies'
    template_name = 'movies/movies_index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
       return Movie.objects.order_by('?')
```

and in template remove `get_random`

```
{% for movie in movies %}
   <a href="{% url 'movies_detail' movie.pk %}">
   <img src="{{ movie.poster }}" class="img-fluid">
{% endfor %}
```

---

Or if you still want to `get_random` then, list all ids of the `movie` objects

```
movie_pks = list(Movie.objects.values_list('id', flat=True))
```

and use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) to select a single `pk`

```
import random
print(random.choice(movie_pks))
```

> **Note:** don't use `random.randint` in your case, because if an object
>   of the movie is deleted then it will fail

Also, remove `while True:` from `get_random` method, you don't need it because you will always get a movie object

```
@property
def get_random(self):
    movie_pks = list(Movie.objects.values_list('id', flat=True))
    pk = random.choice(movie_pks)
    movie = Movie.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return movie
```

and don't call `get_random` 2 times in the template use `with` block

```
{% with rand_movie=movie.get_random %}
    <a href="{% url 'movies_detail' rand_movie.pk %}">
    <img src="{{ rand_movie.poster }}" class="img-fluid">
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This also return one random obj, right? How if I want get a random 10 obj?

Comment: didn't get you, what do you want to achieve, if you just want to list you movie in random order always, you can simply use `.order_by('?')`, and don't need `get_random`

Comment: sorry to get you confuse. I tried with .order_by('?'). But lots of ppl said it slow and cost DB performance. So just want to do another method.

Comment: but calling `get_random` from the template is much heavier than using `order`